# Looking into MaxScale

Tags: database

I am looking to ease the maintenance of working with our databases and having a single point of management that can accomplish the following

- Load balances reads to replicas
- Sends writes only to the master
- If a master fails it automatically promotes one of the replicas to master

A bonus would be if I dont have to setup the replication on the individual servers and it could be managed directly from this software

I think MaxScale checks all these boxes but it is extremally expensive.

So I am wondering is MaxScale worth it or are there better alternatives that are not as expensive